# Why does `awk '/^[^\t]/{a++}END{print a}'` not count the empty lines?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

Why does `awk '/^[^\t]/{a++}END{print a}'` not count the empty lines (i.e. lines which only have new line character)? Isn't an empty line started not with `\t` tab?

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest And you are sure you are testing correctly?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, https://ibb.co/iwHUjw

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Then I guess you have misread the question as it states exactly what you have shown.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I don't think that phrase ***not** count the empty lines* has many different meanings

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - but "why" asks for an explanation, not a confirmation.

Answer (score 20):

The reason is that `[^\t]` requires a character. The newline (`$`) does not count as character. You need this:

```
awk '/^([^\t]|$)/{a++}END{print a}'
```

Comment: `$` is not a newline; it is the end of line, which can also be at the end of file where there is no newline character

Answer (score 20):

Looking for something that isn't X isn't the same as looking for lines that don't contain X.

If we want to find lines that start with a tab, we can use the regex `/^\t/`. To find the opposite, i.e. lines that don't start with a tab, it's probably simplest to put the negation around the whole pattern (instead of in a character class):

```
awk '!/^\t/ {a++} END {print a+0}'
```

`a+0` so that a count of zero comes out as zero, instead of empty.

On the other hand, the regular expression `[^\t]` requires *some* character, it just can't be a tab.

If you want to match empty lines, then `/^$/` or `$0 == ""`. Or to match empty lines or lines with just whitespace `/^[[:space:]]*$/` .

Answer (score 18):

In regex, `[^\t]` doesn't mean "match where there isn't a `\t`". It means "match any character except `\t`". The critical difference is there has to be a character for it to match. In the case of an empty line, there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

I read the matching expression /^[^\t]/ as saying "lines that don't start with a tab". If you're looking for truly empty lines, this ought to work:

```
awk '/^$/{a +=1;};END{print a;}' /your/file/goes/here
```

The '^' means the beginning of the line, and '$' means the ending of the line, so putting them together means there's nothing between beginning and end. I haven't checked how this would behave on a CR-LF delimited line.